# When adding a dimension filter, no results returned (Python - API)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've currently got a Python script that's running through a list of URLs related to a campaign and I'm trying to cross reference these URLS against some different dimensions.

This is the code I currently have:

```
def get_demographics(analytics, page_path):
    return analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': [{
                'viewId': view_id,
                'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2018-01-01', 'endDate': 'today'}],
                'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:pageviews'}],
                'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:userAgeBracket'}],
                'dimensionFilterClauses': [{
                    'filters': [
                        {
                            "dimensionName": "ga:pagePath",
                            "expressions": [page_path]

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
    ).execute()
```

However when I run the code it always returns 0 results.

I have demographics enabled and I have tried the following:

- Changing page views to sessions
- Trying a different dimension (for example gender)
- Removing the filter - This does actually give me results, but of course I need the filter to know what page I'm on

I believe I can cross reference them as when I run it through the query explorer, it outputs the expected results, as well as when I add the filter and dimensions into Google sheets and use the Google sheets addon, the results again appear correct.

Whilst doing both of these are possibilities, the amount of times I have to do this make sense to automate it.

[edit: Just a note to say that if I remove the dimension too, it also works, but again defeats the purpose - so the issue seems to be between the dimension and the dimensionFilterClauses, but I don't know why]

[edit 2: Including an image of query explorer to show using the same dimensions / metrics etc.]

[image]

Comment: Google analytics does not have relations between all dimensions and metrics.  if its returning no data then there is no data for the request you are making.

Comment: Which would have been what I thought the answer would be except the fact that I can get the information through Google Sheets and through the Query Explorer.

Comment: And are you using 100% the exact same request. Same dates same metrics same dimensions same filters.   Same api? (your using v4 above,  query Explorer is v3)

Comment: Yup - I've edited in an image of the query explorer using the dimensions and metrics and the homepage as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was down to data thresholds for Personally Identifiable Information.

Due to the low views of some of the pages, it was showing 0 results. I noticed that on pages which a much higher amount of page views (several thousand) the pageviews were much more visible.

As per the data thresholds section [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Specs for the dimension filter: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#DimensionFilter

I think you're missing an operator or it is defaulting to regex, try "EXACT".

```
'dimensionFilterClauses': [{
                    'filters': [
                        {
                            "dimensionName": "ga:pagePath",
                            "operator": "EXACT",
                            "expressions": [page_path]

                        }
                    ]
```

Comment: I've tried EXACT and that doesn't work - if you don't add an operator, by default it uses REGEXP which is what I need anyway.

Comment: Yes if it is regex, do you have the "/" character escaped?

Comment: I shouldn't need to escape / characters as they don't work as operators. Also when I remove the dimension and keep the filter, the code works so the issue isn't the operator. I also have the exact same filter running on a separate query which works with no issues.

Comment: can you show us a report in GA with age as the primary dimension and page as the secondary?

Comment: If you look at my edited post I've put an example of the query explorer with the output I'd expect.

Comment: I'm trying to see what the pagepath data looks like. If you also pull the "page" dimension it will help me to see what is matching.